# Business Entity - should lists be exposed only as ReadOnlyCollections?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, business-objects

In trying to centralize how items are added, or removed from my business entity classes, I have moved to the model where all lists are only exposed as ReadOnlyCollections and I provide Add and Remove methods to manipulate the objects in the list.

Here is an example:

```
public class Course
{
    public string Name{get; set;}
}

public class Student
{
    private List<Course>_courses = new List<Course>();
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Course> Courses {
        get{ return _courses.AsReadOnly();}
    }
    public void Add(Course course)
    {
        if (course != null && _courses.Count <= 3)
        {
            _courses.Add(course);
        }
    }
    public bool Remove(Course course)
    {
        bool removed = false;
        if (course != null && _courses.Count <= 3)
        {
            removed = _courses.Remove(course);
        }
        return removed;
    }
}
```

Part of my objective in doing the above is to not end up with an Anemic data-model (an anti-pattern) and also avoid having the logic that adds and removes courses all over the place.

Some background: the application I am working with is an Asp.net application, where the lists used to be exposed as a list previously, which resulted in all kinds of ways in which Courses were added to the Student (some places a check was made and others the check was not made).

But my question is: is the above a good idea?

Comment: I usually expose IEnumerable<> instead of ReadOnlyCollection, since Count() etc. are optimized on the runtime type anyway, theres no significant performance loss asociated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a good approach, in my opinion you're not doing anything than decorating your list, and its better than implementing your own IList (as you save many lines of code, even though you lose the more elegant way to iterate through your Course objects).

You may consider receiving a validation strategy object, as in the future you might have a new requirement, for ex: a new kind of student that can have more than 3 courses, etc

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is a good idea when adding/removing needs to be controlled in the manner you suggest, such as for business rule validation.  Otherwise, as you know from previous code, there's really no way to ensure that the validation is performed.

The balance that you'll probably want to reach, however, is when to do this and when not to.  Doing this for every collection of every kind seems like overkill.  However, if you *don't* do this and then later need to add this kind of gate-keeping code then it would be a breaking change for the class, which may or may not be a headache at the time.

I suppose another approach could be to have a custom descendant of `IList<T>` which has generic gate-keeping code for its `Add()` and `Remove()` methods which notifies the system of what's happening.  Something like exposing an event which is raised before the internal logic of those methods is called.  Then the `Student` class would supply a delegate or something (sorry for being vague, I'm very coded-out today) when instantiating `_courses` to apply business logic to the event and cancel the operation (throw an exception, I imagine) if the business validation fails.

That could be overkill as well, depending on the developer's disposition.  But at least with something a little more engineered like this you get a single generic implementation for everything with the option to add/remove business validation as needed over time without breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've done that in the past and regretted it: a better option is to use **different classes** to read domain objects than the ones you use to modify them.

For example, use a behavior-rich `Student` domain class that jealously guards its ownership of courses - it shouldn't expose them at all if student is responsible for them - and a `StudentDataTransferObject` (or `ViewModel`) that provides a simple list of strings of courses (or a dictionary when you need IDs) for populating interfaces.